# Codeigniter active record return column name of specified row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is it possible to return the column name of a row in a table? If so, how should I do it?

I have a table with this structure

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| idx | line1 | line2 | line3 | line1_action | line2_action | line3_action |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   3   |   2   |   1   |    PENDING   |    PENDING   |   APPROVED   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For example i have an `idx = 1` and my `line = 2`, and I need to check if I am in the lines 1, 2 or 3 of `idx = 1`, How do I return the column name that I am in?

**ANSWERED MY OWN QUESTION**

```
$requestIdx = $this->session->userdata('request_id');
$staffDepth = 2;
$requestInfo = $this->staffrequisition_model->selectItem(array('idx'=>$requestIdx));
foreach($requestInfo as $key=>$value){
    if(preg_match('/line\d/',$key) && $value == $staffDepth) { $lineName = $key; }
}
```

Comment: A better solution is to structure your tables differently. Create a lines table with an ID and status and then query only against the table which is approved. You can check using IF but imagine if you want to add 5 lines? Your IF query will suddenly become unworkable. A different table structure will suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return column name directly.

For that, you have to prepare query like as below way

```
SELECT idx, IF(line1 = 2, 'line1', if(line2 = 2, 'line2', line3 = 3, 'line3', '')) AS line, line2, line3 FROM table_name WHERE (line1 = 2 OR line2 = 2 OR line3 = 2) AND idx = 1
```